# Bootstrap div with variable height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating one of those scroll-through websites where you just scroll down through pages. My pages alternate black and white background.

I have the following page:

```
<div class="row>
 <div class="col-xs-9 introduction">
  <p> TEXT </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.introduction {
height: 120%;
padding-top: 150px;
text-align: center;
background: #eee;
min-height: 800px;
```

}

My problem is that when I make the window of my browser narrow enough, the TEXT in my intro section overflows the white background and spills over to the black section.
How do I specify the size of the class so that all the text is always within the white background??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you cannot read the documentation.

```
<div class="col-xs-9 introduction">
  <p> TEXT </p>
</div>
```

Here in this code this class 'col-xs-9', xs is used to make sure that the column remains horizontal at all times so your responsive settings aren't properly arranged the way they should be.

I'll suggest that you read the documentation about the grid system a little.

use this instead

```
<div class="col-md-9 introduction">
  <p> TEXT </p>
</div>
```

it wont give you any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow for the text parent

To hide the text or make scroll

Or you can use [nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) vs [slimscroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll)

[Overflow MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this css to fix:

```
.introduction {
height: 100vh;
padding-top: 150px;
text-align: center;
background: #eee;
max-height:100%;
}
```